# How do I return an object when I only have access to one field of it?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I can't think of a better way to phrase it. Hopefully my code illustrates my problem better.

So in this method I want to return a Myuser object. A Myuser object has about 8 string fields, one of which is userId.

As you can see, when this method is called, a string is passed in. If this string has the same value as the userId field in the Myuser object, then I want it to return the full Myuser object. Otherwise it returns null.

```
public Myuser getRecord(String userId) {
    Connection cnnct = null;
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = null;
    Myuser myusr = null;
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        cnnct = getConnection();
        String preQueryStatement = "SELECT * FROM MYUSER WHERE USERID = ?";
        pStmnt = cnnct.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);

        pStmnt.setString(1, userId);

        ResultSet rslt = pStmnt.executeQuery();

        result = rslt.next();

        if (result) {
            //return myusr in its entirety
        }

     } catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ex = ex.getNextException();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (pStmnt != null) {
            try {
                pStmnt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        if (cnnct != null) {
            try {
                cnnct.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            }
        }
    }

    return myusr;
}
```

Edit: I thought for the heck of it I would post the Myuser class as well.

```
public class Myuser {

    private String userid;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private String secQn;
    private String secAns;

    public Myuser(String userid, String name, String password, String email, String phone, String address, String secQn, String secAns) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.secQn = secQn;
        this.secAns = secAns;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSecQn() {
        return secQn;
    }

    public void setSecQn(String secQn) {
        this.secQn = secQn;
    }

    public String getSecAns() {
        return secAns;
    }

    public void setSecAns(String secAns) {
        this.secAns = secAns;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use just a plain jdbc connector, which I strongly believe you do, you have to grab the information from the Result you got to create a new Myuser Object with that specific information

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `result.getXXX(field_name)`:

```
if (rslt.next()) {
   myusr = new Myuser(result.getString("userid"), result.getString("name"), 
                      result.getString("password"), result.getString("phone"),  
                      ...);
}
```

**Note** don't need to use `result = rslt.next();` before `if(result)`, you have to use directly

```
if (rslt.next()) {
   ...
}
```